# Do I need to set a password for every root account entry? - MySQL

Tags: mysql, passwords, mariadb

This is my current user account configuration:

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User     | Host       | Password                                  |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root     | localhost  | *CAB56DA385754BF21E94AC7D75E8B51EA0F468A8 |
| root     | centos-gcp |                                           |
| root     | 127.0.0.1  |                                           |
| root     | ::1        |                                           |
|          | localhost  |                                           |
|          | centos-gcp |                                           |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

So far I only added a `root` password during installation.

From what I understand, each `'username'@'host'` combination is treated as  a different account.

Does that mean that I need to set a password for every root account?

Or does the first password apply to all other root accounts?

It seems that if I try to log in with `'root'@'centos-gcp'` which resolves to `127.0.1.1` I still have to enter the main password (I'm somewhat confused by all these hostnames).

Comment: I just keep one account then I don't have to change all of them for password changes.

Comment: @eckes So they are different then? Do you know why using `mysql -h centos-gcp -u root - p` still asks me for password even though no password is set?

Comment: Actually, I think I can't specify the hostname like that. It says `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host 'centos-gcp.c.lively-tensor-163604.internal' is not allowed to connect to this MariaDB server`

Comment: Your tries will most likely all map to 'root'@'localhost', there is no point in risking the others with no password are used, just remove them.

Comment: Great, that simplifies things.

Comment: BTW @rtsne42 you can specify the hostname fully qualified like that, you have to keep in mind 2 resolving happen: the mysql client will turn the name into IP address . The server now sees a connection from the automatically chosen source(!) IP of the client. In case both is local and the IP is a net interface the source will be the same IP.Now the this IP is reverse resolved into a name.Now the mysqld authentication logic searches for entries with the name, the IP or host wildcard. 'cents-gcp' with nomdomain is only matched if it is first hostname in /etc/hosts line for that client.

Comment: ... if all clients remember to connect to localhost (or Unix domain Socket) the localhost entry is enough. This entry will also work when resolving ismturned off, which is actually a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a password, you have a vulnerability that a hacker may discover.

If you have never needed to use `root` after installing, then either you have not *yet* needed to do some serious maintenance, or you have given your other users too much privilege, thereby opening up another class of vulnerability.

Your multiple `root@...` logins *are* different.  They are distinguished by where 'root' is coming from within the system, and how the connection is being made (socket vs TCP with IPv4 vs IPv6), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think it misses the question slightly. The main question was whether these root+host combinations are treated as different accounts (need separate passwords) or are they treated as one localhost account (need only one password)

Comment: I added to my answer.